# Calculating Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution

Tags: c, precision, floating-accuracy, scientific-computing

I am trying to calculate Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution but this code gives 0.00000, what is the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{

    float e=2.718228183, pi=3.14159265, m=2.66*pow(10,-23), t, k=1.38*pow(10,-23), v, result;

    scanf("%f %f", &t, &v);

    result = sqrt(pow( m / (2*pi*k*t),   3))   * 4 * pi * pow(v,2) * pow(e, -(m * pow(v,2)) / (2*k*t)); 

    printf("%f", result);
}
```

Comment: The code gives `0.000000` for *what* input values?

Comment: now gives just 0 @SvenMarnach

Comment: for example 500 100 @WeatherVane

Comment: And what *should* it print? BTW I don't know why you are using `float`. Is your system unable to use `double`?

Comment: double also gives 0.000000 @WeatherVane

Comment: When I change the variable type to `double` (and the `scanf` formats to `%lf`), and ask for 20 decimal places, those inputs give `0.00000000812775485664`.

Comment: Please note that the math library provides values for **e** and **π** and there is also the function `exp` which does what you are using `pow(e, ...)` for.

Comment: Aside: your Boltzmann constant is given as `k=1.38*pow(10,-23)`. I would suggest `k=1.3806485279e-23`. Similarly your initialisation of `m` needlessly calls the `pow` function.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the comments, the use of `float` together with the reduced precision of the constants give a result that is not representable anymore as a `float`. Changing the data type to double alone gives two decimal digits of accuracy. If we use `exp`, more digits for pi and do a bit of recombination of the computations we get 12 digits of accuracy. E.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{

  double pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028842, m = 2.66e-23, k =
      1.38e-23;
  double t, v, v2, dkt, result;
  // check omitted
  scanf("%lf %lf", &t, &v);

  v2 = v * v;
  dkt = 2 * k * t;

  result = pow(m / (pi * dkt), 3 / 2.0) * 4 * pi * v2 * exp(-(m * v2) / (dkt));
  printf("%.20g\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

The result from Pari/GP is `8.1246636077915008261803395870165527173e-9` and the result we get with the code above is `8.1246636077914841125e-09`. Without the intermediate results `v2`, `dkt` and the replacement of `sqrt` we got `8.1246636077914824582e-09`, not much of a difference, especially with accuracy where it gained nothing.

If you want the full 16 decimal digits of accuracy you need to take the whole thing apart and take a different approach.

Comment: The real fix in your code is accidental. With `printf("%e", result);`, the OP's code calculates `8.127763e-09`. The other changes are mostly fluff...

Comment: @EOF the code above is not meant as a fix, as made clear by the last sentence. At least I thought it--the  last sentence--would be able to make it clear, that there is no immediate fix, only with a completely different approach. A double-double (the 112 bit double-double) might do it for some limited but probably sufficiently large range but I didn't do a complete analysis of the computation. The `exp` and `pow(x,y)` ( = `exp(y log x)`) would suggest a series and a minimax poly for it found with Remez or similar (e.g. with the help of http://lolengine.net/wiki/oss/lolremez).

Comment: The OP's mistake is *probably* not that the n-th decimal digit is wrong. The OP's problem was that the result was *completely useless* due to the idiocy of `%f` as a `printf()`-conversion specifier.

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
double pi=acos(-1.);
```

instead of

```
 double pi=3.1415926535897932384626433832795028842;
```